# Is there a way to use import for a list of packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I would like to know if it is possible to use `import` in a list data structure or dict for example  in python instead of repeating the `import` statement for every packages?

An example:

```py
import {
    asyncio,
    asyncpg,
    datetime,
    os,
    sys
}
```

The classical way:

```py
import asyncio
import asyncpg
import datetime
import os
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) can take a comma-separated sequence of modules to import.

```
import asyncio, asyncpg, datetime, os, sys
```

You can split this into multiple lines using line continuations

```
import asyncio, \
       asyncpg, \
       datetime, 
       os, \
       sys
```

That said, the *recommended* way to import multiple modules is as a series of `import` statements, one module per statement.

Comment: thanks for the answer. For the "recommended" way, I find it not very elegant because it is repetitive and not concise. But it is just a point of view ^^. Actually, the last "solution" raises an exception.

Comment: It's recommended because it's simple, readable, and makes for simple diffs in version control.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM That's what I get for not checking and relying on a hazy memory. Removed.

Comment: It's `from foo import (bar, baz)` that allows parentheses.